Inkscape path direction indicators difficult to see
In Inkscape I often need to be able to reverse the direction of a path. I have enabled path direction indicators via…
Preferences > Node > Show path direction on outlines (See this answer for details)
…and they are present albeit very thin and difficult for me to see without zooming in and out repeatedly.
Is there a setting / method to adjust the weight of the path direction indicator itself (UI element not the actual path) to increase visibility?
I’ve looked through the preferences options and tried tinkering with stroke settings but can only seem to influence the paths not the path indicator.
I thought tweaking the CSS Inkscape uses (suggested on the Inkscape forum for a different issue)  might be the way to go but I haven't had any luck as yet.
I've attached a basic example...

Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated.
